# Error installing W3C validator on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, w3c-validation, apt-get, apache2.4

I'm installing W3C validator locally on Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache 2.4.7.

I do `sudo apt-get install w3c-markup-validator` and get this:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/etc/apache2/conf.d/w3c-markup-validator.conf’: No such file or directory
```

Seems the script is using a different directory structure instead of linking to /etc/apache2/conf-available.

Where do I find this install script to make the change? I'm not familiar with apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

Edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/w3c-markup-validator.postinst` and comment out lines 41-44.

Then:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/w3c/httpd.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/w3c-markup-validator.conf
```